# C++, using environment variables for paths

Tags: c++, file, unicode, io

is there any way to use environment variables in c++ for path to file?
Idea is to use them without expending so I don't need to use `wchar` for languages with unicode standard when I want to save/read file.

//EDIT

Little edit with more explanations.

So what I try to achieve is to read/write to file without worrying about characters in path. So I don't want to use `wchar` as path but it should work if path contains some wide chars.

There are functions `getenv` and `GetEnvironmentVariable` but they need to set proper language in `Language for non-Unicode programs` in windows settings (`Constrol Panel` -> `Clock, Language, and Region` -> `Region and Language` -> `Administrative`) which need some actions from users and this is something that I try to avoid.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv

Comment: Please read carefully my post before you give me a minus. WITHOUT expanding variable. As far as I know `getenv` convert environment variable to full path.

Comment: If you set an environment variable, it takes that value.  If you get the variable, you get that value.  There's no expanding done in the getting ever, although if you use something like `export foo=~/bar` your expanding will be done at the time of setting

Comment: @Derag `getenv` doesn't do any expanding; if `getenv` returns a full path, the variable was already set to a full path. And it's very unclear what the connection to Unicode is.

Comment: By expanding I meant that I don't need to get value of variable. Otherwise I need to care If language use `wide chars`. Idea is to open file with path like: 
`"%UserProfile%\\something"`
so I can use just `char`

Comment: @Derag if `getenv` gives you an Unicode string (probably UTF-8, since it has to fit into `char`s), you can feed it back to functions expectig paths without problem -- you don't have any encoding manipulation to do.

Comment: @Derag That's not a valid path - it *has* to be expanded. On Windows, you could use the functions for getting "special folders".

Comment: @Quentin but does it works like `GetEnvironmentVariable`? If so users need to change settings in their system first, otherwise it will be invalid path. And this is undesirable behavior. Thanks for really quick answers by the way.

Comment: @Derag I don't understand. Which settings would have to be changed ? From a glance at the documentation, it looks like it works just like `getenv`.

Comment: Can you please update your question with exactly what you're expecting to try to read, what you're expected output is, and what you've tried; as I think everyone involved is now confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are functions getenv and GetEnvironmentVariable but they need to set proper language in Language for non-Unicode programs in windows settings

This is specifically a Windows problem.

On other platforms such as Linux, filepaths and environment variables are natively byte-based; you can access them using the standard C library functions that take byte-string paths like `fopen()` and `getenv()`. The pathnames may represent Unicode strings to the user (decoded using some encoding, almost always UTF-8 which can encode any character), but to the code they're just byte strings.

Windows, on the other hand, has filenames and environment variables that are natively strings of 16-bit (UTF-16) code units (which are nearly the same thing as Unicode character code points, but not quite, because that would be too easy... but that's a sadness for another time). You can call Win32 file-handling APIs like `CreateFileW()` and `GetEnvironmentVariableW()` using UTF-16 code unit strings (`wchar_t`, when compiled on Windows) and access any file names directly.

There are also old-school legacy byte-based Win32 functions like `GetEnvironmentVariableA()` (which is what `GetEnvironmentVariable()` points to if you are compiling a non-Unicode project). If you call those functions, Windows has to convert from the `char` byte strings you give it to UTF-16 strings, using some encoding.
That encoding is the ‘ANSI’ (‘A’) locale-specific default code page, which is what “Language for non-Unicode programs” sets.

Although that encoding can be changed by the user, it can't be set to UTF-8 or any other encoding that supports all characters, so even if you ask the user to change it, that still doesn't let you access all files. Thus the Win32 `A` APIs are always to be avoided.

The problem comes when you want to access files in a manner that works on both Windows and the other platforms. If you call the C standard library with byte strings, the Microsoft C runtime library adapts those calls to call the Win32 `A` byte-based APIs, which as above are irritatingly limited.

So your unattractive choices are:

1. use `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` strings in your code, using only Win32 APIs for interacting with filenames and environment variables, and accepting that your code will never run on other platforms, or;
2. use `char` and UTF-8-encoded `std::string` strings, and give up on your code accessing filenames and environment variables with non-ASCII characters in on Windows, or;
3. write a load of branching `#ifdef` code to switch between using C standard functions for filename and environment interaction, or using Win32 APIs with a bunch of UTF-8-`char`-to-`wchar_t` string conversions in between, so that code works across multiple platforms, or;
4. use a library that encapsulates (3) for you.
   Notably there is [boost::nowide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/nowide/doc/html/index.html) (since Boost 1.73) which contains [boost::nowide::getenv](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/nowide/doc/html/namespaceboost_1_1nowide.html#ac83059bedb191bbcb73637cd1224589c).

This isn't entirely Microsoft's fault: Windows NT was designed in their early days of Unicode before UTF-8 or the astral planes were invented, when it was thought that 16-bit code unit strings were a totally sensible way to store text, and not a lamentable disaster like we know it is now. It is, however, very sad that Windows has not been updated since then to treat UTF-8 as a first-class citizen and provide an easy way to write cross-platform applications.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library gives you the function *getenv*. Here is an example:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    char* pPath;
    pPath = getenv("PATH");
    if (pPath)
        std::cout << "Path =" << pPath << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```